# Need alternate class for SHA512Managed() and HMACSHA512() under FIPS in 2.0, 3.5 .Net framework

Tags: c#, cryptography, hmac, sha512, fips

I need alternation for SHA512Managed, HMACSHA512 cryptography algorithm under FIPS mode compilation in 2.0, 3.5 framework version.
How to achieve this under FIPS compliance

```
m_hashAlgorithm = new SHA512Managed();
m_hmacSha = new HMACSHA512();
```

Comment: I need this scenario in 4.0 framework